# I want to select the # users_read in the last row for each book_id and calculate mean

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset table that's set like this

```
Year | Book_id | Event_num | Users_read

 2018.   1.        1            14 
 2018.   1.        2            13
 2018.   2.        3            15
 2018.   1.        4            13
 2018.   2.        5            12
```

I want to select the last row for each book_id in the year 2018 to find the mean in R. So for this sample data above I would be selecting 13 users_read for book_id = 1 and 12 for book_id = 2. Then mean = 25/2

Comment: Can you please `dput(head(data))` your `data`, and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of how you can do that using `dplyr` package.

```
# Loading Required libraries
library(dplyr)

# Creating sample data
example <- read.table(text ='
Year|Book_id|Event_num|Users_read
2018.|1.|1|14
2018.|1.|2|13
2018.|2.|3|15
2018.|1.|4|13
2018.|2.|5|12',header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "|")

example %>%
  # Filtering to get data for 2018 only
  filter(Year == "2018") %>%
  # Grouping by Book_id
  group_by(Book_id) %>%
  # Selecting last occurance for each book_id
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Calculating average
  summarize(avg_users_read = mean(Users_read))
```

Comment: TY can I add multiple functions to summarize, such as med, mode etc

Comment: yes for sure. It can be summarize(avg_users_read = mean(Users_read), med_users_read = median(Users_read), mode_users_read = mode(Users_read))

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution using the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Year == 2018, last(Users_read), by = Book_id][, mean(V1)]
```

> [1] 12.5

#### Data

```
df1 <- data.table::fread("
Year  Book_id  Event_num  Users_read
 2018.   1.        1            14 
 2018.   1.        2            13
 2018.   2.        3            15
 2018.   1.        4            13
 2018.   2.        5            12")
```

---

Just out of curiosity, I tried to find a [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) solution as well:

```
sqldf::sqldf(
"select avg(Users_read)
   from df1 A
   inner join (select Year, Book_id, max(Event_num) Last_event from df1
     where Year = 2018
     group by Year, Book_id) B
   where A.Year = B.Year and A.Book_id = B.Book_id and A.Event_num = B.Last_event"
)
```

> ```
>   avg(Users_read)
> 1            12.5
> ```